# R DBI ODBC error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3110: 07009: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid Descriptor Index

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, r-dbi, nanodbc

I continue to read the `DBI/ODBC` is faster than `RODBC`, so I tried as follows:

```
require(DBI);require(odbc)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = 'SQLSERVER1', database = 'AcumaticaDB')
```

I can make a successful connection to the DSN, but the following query:

```
rs <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM inventoryitem")
dbFetch(rs)
```

gives me the following error:

> Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n, ...) : 
>     nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3110: 07009: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid Descriptor Index

What am I doing wrong ?
Please, no `RODBC` solutions.
Thanks!

Comment: Leaving out `dbFetch()`, does *rs* come through as a dataframe?

Comment: From [the source and man page](https://github.com/rstats-db/DBI/blob/258b967659dc6a6c984e49b8494122d3f27bd23b/R/DBConnection.R#L160-L164), `dbGetQuery() ... calls 'dbSendQuery()', then 'dbFetch()', ensuring that the result is always free-d by 'dbClearResult()'`.

Comment: rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM InventoryItem") : this works and creates rs as class <odbcresult> (it's not a dataframe)
dbFetch(rs) : gives me the error: "Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n, ...) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3110: 07009: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid Descriptor Index"

Comment: I have the same problem as you have and came to the conclusion that it has to be a bug. I wound up returning to RODBC instead which while a bit  slower atleast works.

Comment: This is a known issue, see [here](https://github.com/rstats-db/odbc/issues/86).

Answer (score 20):

I appreciate that this question was asked a long time ago, but I've managed to find a workaround. The answers above got me most of the way there. The problem I had was with columns of type nvarchar that had a CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH in the schema table of -1, which I understand means they are the maximum length possible.

My solution was to lookup the relevant table in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table and then rearrange my fields appropriately:

```
require(DBI);require(odbc)
library(tidyverse)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = 'SQLSERVER1', database = 'AcumaticaDB')

column.types <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='inventoryitem'")

ct <- column.types %>%
  mutate(cml = case_when(
    is.na(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) ~ 10,
    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH == -1 ~ 100000,
    TRUE ~ as.double(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)
    )
  ) %>%
  arrange(cml) %>%
  pull(COLUMN_NAME)

fields <- paste(ct, collapse=", ")
query <- paste("SELECT", fields, "FROM inventoryitems")

tbl(con, sql(query)) %>% head(5)
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. You sir are a god among mere mortals. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

I have also been struggling with this issue for several months. However, I have come across a solution that may help you as well.

In a nutshell, the issue occurs when certain text columns do not appear after integer/numeric columns. When the columns are not aligned properly in the query, an error of `invalid index` is thrown and your connection may freeze. **The issue then is, how do I know what to put at the end of my query?**

To determine this, one could typically examine a column using `class()` or `typeof()`. To examine such information from the database, you can use a query such as:

```
dbColumnInfo(dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * from schema.table")) # You may not require the schema part...
```

This will return a table with a type field for every column in the data-set of interest. You can then use this table as an index to sort the `select()` statement. My particular difficulty is that the `type` field in the table was all numbers! However, I noticed that every column with a negative number, when placed at the end of the select statement, fixed my query and I could pull the whole table just fine. For example, **my full solution**:

```
# Create my index of column types (ref to the current order)
index <- dbColumnInfo(dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * from schema.table"))
index$type <- as.integer(index$type) # B/c they are + and - numbers!

# Create the ref to the table
mySQLTbl <- tbl(con, in_schema("schema", "tablename"))

# Use the select statement to put all the + numbered columns first!
mySQLTbl %>%
  select(c(which(index$type>=0),
                 which(index$type<0)))
```

As for reason for why this occurs, I am not sure and I do not have the data access privileges to dig much deeper in my use-case

Comment: Thanks for this workaround.  I've read that we have to downgrade to 1.1.6 by `devtools::install_github("r-dbi/odbc@v1.1.6")`. Here is the issue on github : [github/r-dbi/odbc #309: Error "Invalid descriptor index" when collecting a table with a blob column in the middle](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/309).  This downgrading to 1.1.6 works.

Answer (score 9):

There is a workaround:

Reorder your `SELECT` statements such that longer datatypes (typically strings) are last.

If you have a complex query that is generated by `dbplyr` itself, then get the SQL query directly via `show_query()`. Copy-paste and modify the first `SELECT` statement such that long datatypes are last in the list. It should then work.

EDIT:
in many cases it is possible to reorder the fields by adding this to the query:

```
%>% select(var1, var2, textvar1, textvar2)
```

Comment: So, @mzuba, how (generically) do we *know* that the underlying DBMS believes a field to be "large"? The documentation does not indicate a fixed cutoff, so it is not only specific to SQL Server, but also perhaps instance-specific (meaning what is "large" on one server may not be large on another).

Comment: I dont't know if we can find out which fields are 'large'. This is a workaround and not a solution.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> rs <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM inventoryitem")
> dbFetch(rs)
> ```

If `inventoryitem` table contains mix of long data/variable-length columns (eg. `VARBINARY`, `VARCHAR`) and columns of simple types (eg. `INT`), you can not query them in arbitrary order via ODBC.

Applications should make sure to place long data columns at the end of the select list.

Long data is retrieved from database using ODBC API call `SQLGetData` and it 
has to be retrieved after the other data in the row has been fetched.

These are known and documented ODBC restrictions

> To retrieve long data from a column, an application first calls
>   SQLFetchScroll or SQLFetch to move to a row and fetch the data for
>   bound columns. The application then calls SQLGetData.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/getting-long-data

Comment: Does this infect non-Windows ODBC as well? Seems to me it's an abject breakage of the "S" in SQL.

Comment: Okay, that's a myth (to which I succumbed), the "S" is for *structured* not *standard*, but that doesn't change (in my mind) my reservation about needing to know that much detail about a table's storage/structure.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else comes across this SO question....

I also was having a problem with the using the `SELECT * FROM table` statement with a setup like this:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "SQL Server",
                      Server   = "CorporateServer",
                      Database = "DB_of_Interest",
                      Port     = 1433)

sql <- "SELECT TOP (10) *
  FROM [DB_of_Interest].[dbo].[tb_of_interest]"

dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

Which generated this error:

```
Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3069: 07009: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index 
Warning message:
In dbClearResult(rs) : Result already cleared
```

## My Solution

After looking at [RStudio -- Connect to a Database](https://db.rstudio.com/getting-started/connect-to-database), I looked to see what other drivers might be available to me:

```
sort(unique(odbcListDrivers()[[1]]))

 [1] "Amazon Redshift (x64)"                                 
 [2] "Hortonworks Hive ODBC Driver"                          
 [3] "Hortonworks Spark ODBC Driver"                         
 [4] "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)"              
 [5] "Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)"           
 [6] "Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)"
 [7] "MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver"                            
 [8] "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver"                         
 [9] "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"                         
[10] "PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)"                                  
[11] "PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)"                               
[12] "Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery"                 
[13] "SQL Server"                                            
[14] "SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
```

And #9 caught my eye: `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`.  I went into the Windows Control Panel, and set up a new ODBC Data Source using that particular driver (in my case, I named it "Buyer Central 2" and I have Integrated Windows authentication, so no username/password), and then revised my R code to be:

```
con2 <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       dsn = "Buyer Central 2")

dbGetQuery(con2, sql)
```

Now the sql statement with the glob (*) works for me.

### Alternative that doesn't work (for me)

I thought and tried to use the other ODBC driver without the formal setup in the data source administrator:

```
con3 <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                      Server   = "CorporateServer",
                      Database = "DB_of_Interest",
                      Port     = 1433)
```

But that line fails for me with the following:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 01S00: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute
```

I searched for a reason why it works when set up in admin tools, but not as above, and [found comments related to SQL Server 2014](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/460) not working with this driver due to SSL issues, but I checked my version and I'm using SQL Server 2016... so not that.  Curious why it doesn't work this way, but the above solution does work.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly encountered this problem recently. Here is my solution. 
Basically you have to reorder columns based on the column information fetched from the database first. Columns could mix with positive and negative types. So sorting them with positive first, then negative will do the trick.

It works perfectly with my data when having "Invalid Descriptor Index" issue. Please let me know whether it works for you too.

```
sqlFetchData <- function(connection, database, schema, table, nobs = 'All') {

  #'wrap function to fetch data from SQL Server
  #
  #@ connection: an established odbc connection
  #@ database: database name
  #@ schema: a schema under the main database
  #@ table: the name of the data table to be fetched. 
  #@ nobs: number of observation to be fetched. Either 'All' or an integer number. 
  #        The default value is 'All'. It also supports the input of 'all', 'ALL' and
  #        etc. . 

  if (is.character(nobs)) {
    if (toupper(nobs) == 'ALL') {
      obs_text <- 'select'
    } else {
      stop("nobs could either be 'ALL' or a scalar integer number")
    }
  } else {
    if (is.integer(nobs) && length(nobs) == 1) {
      obs_text <- paste('select top ', nobs, sep = '')
    } else {
      stop("nobs could either be 'ALL' or a scalar integer number")
    }
  }

  initial_sql <- paste("select * from ", database, '.', schema, ".", table, 
                       sep = '')
  dbquery <- dbSendQuery(connection, initial_sql)
  cols <- dbColumnInfo(dbquery) 
  dbClearResult(dbquery)

  #' sort the rows by query type due to error message:
  #' Invalid Descriptor Index 

  colInfo <- cols
  colInfo$type <- as.integer(colInfo$type)
  cols_neg <- colInfo[which(colInfo$type < 0), ]
  cols_neg <- cols_neg[order(cols_neg[, 2]), ]
  cols_pos <- colInfo[which(colInfo$type >= 0), ]
  cols_pos <- cols_pos[order(cols_pos[, 2]), ]
  cols <- rbind(cols_pos, cols_neg)

  add_comma <- "c(cols$name[1], paste(',', cols$name[-1L], sep = ''))"

  sql1 <- paste(c(obs_text, eval(parse(text = add_comma))),
                collapse = ' ', sep = '')
  data_sql <- paste(sql1, ' from ', database, '.', schema, '.', table, 
                    sep = '')

  dataFetch <- dbGetQuery(connection, data_sql)[, colInfo$name]
  return(dataFetch)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ODBC/DBI convert character variable data type in the database into 'ntext' while making the connection. So, you need to convert your character variables (say x) in the SQL string in R as CONVERT(varchar(100),x). Then dbGetQuery function should work.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same problem. The short and the easiest solution is to find the column info first and place the column at the end with max values(suppose ***varchar(max) and or varbinary(max)***). Try the example below.

**With Error**

```
library(DBI)
library(ODBC)
myquery<- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM MYTABLE")

Error in Result_fetch....:  Invalid Descriptor Index
```

**Solution**

```
dbcolumnInfo(dbSendWuery(con,"SELECT * FROM MYTABLE")
```

[image: Output of dbcolumninfo()]

As you can see the datatype for **DateTimeSampled** is varchar(max). Place this data column at the end while retrieving the columns of ***MYTABLE*** using following query.

```
myquery<- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT [PROCHI],[hb_extract],
[QuantityValue],[QuantityUnit],[Interpretation],
[LabNumber],[LocalClinicalCodeValue],[DateTimeSampled]
FROM MYTABLE")
```

*Enjoy SQL with R*

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as a result of trying to load in a timestamp variable. Try removing any timestamp variables from your query.

Try the below or similar. Let me know what works and I'll update my post.

```
require(DBI);require(odbc)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = 'SQLSERVER1', database = 'AcumaticaDB')

column.types = DBI::dbGetQuery( 
    con, 
    'SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = "inventoryitem"' 
))

sql = paste(c(
        'select ', 
        paste(column.types$COLUMN_NAME[column.types$DATA_TYPE != 'timestamp'], collapse = ', '), 
        ' from inventoryitem'
     ),
    collapse = ''
)

dbFetch(dbGetQuery(con, sql))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you have a field of type `geometry`. You should `SELECT AS` and use a spatial method to convert to WKT before pulling into a data.table. See below, where you know that `Shape` is a field of type `geometry`. By using the spatial method `.STAsText()` it converts it to Well-Known Text (WKT) format, which R can work with more easily.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

query <- "
SELECT company, revenue, address, Shape.STAsText() AS ShapeWKT
FROM businesses_table
"

results <- dbFetch(dbSendQuery(con, query)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(ShapeWKT)) %>%
  mutate(Shape = st_as_sfc(ShapeWKT)) %>%
  select(-ShapeWKT) %>%
  st_as_sf()
```

I built a more complex function that allows you to specify a db connection, table name, a field exception (defaults to return all fields EXCEPT those in `exception` field), a WHERE clause to filter your query, and specify a spatial field name, since it varies from table to table (i.e., could be `Shape` could be `Geo`, etc.).

```
spatial_query <- function(con, tablename, 
                          exception = "", 
                          wherefilter = "", 
                          spatialfieldname = "Shape",
                          spatial = TRUE){
  ## Get last element (table name) from explicit table name
  tmp <- strsplit(tablename, "[.]")[[1]]
  tablename_short <- tmp[length(tmp)]
  
  fields <- dbListFields(con, tablename_short)
  
  if(spatial){
    fields_to_grab <- fields[!(fields %in% c(exception, spatialfieldname))]
    ## TODO adjust query to be responsive to Shape
    qstring <- paste0('SELECT ', paste(fields_to_grab, collapse = ", "), ', ', spatialfieldname, '.STAsText() AS ShapeWKT FROM ', tablename, ' ', wherefilter)
    cat(paste("Sending following SQL statement:", qstring, "\n", sep = "\n"))
    ret <- dbFetch(dbSendQuery(con, qstring)) %>%
      filter(!is.na(ShapeWKT)) %>%
      mutate(Shape = st_as_sfc(ShapeWKT)) %>%
      select(-ShapeWKT) %>%
      st_as_sf()
  }
  
  else{
    fields_to_grab <- fields[!(fields %in% exception)]
    qstring <- paste0('SELECT ', paste(fields_to_grab, collapse = ", "),' FROM ', tablename, ' ', wherefilter)
    cat(paste("Sending following SQL statement:", qstring, "\n", sep = "\n"))
    ret <- dbFetch(dbSendQuery(con, qstring))
  }
  
  return(ret)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed someone else adding this, but I had this exact same error, read through this string and tried several elaborate things like reordering columns, and didn't know how to solve it for several months. Then, I found out that I just had to upgrade to the most recent SQL Server Driver for my Windows 10 and change the driver in my connection string, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Today I came across the exact same problem but for me it turned out to be the types of my table that were causing it.

I had an id INT and 3 other columnheaders with VARCHAR(MAX) and one more with VARCHAR(50).

For some reason it didn't like it that one was VARCHAR(50) so I changed it from 50 to MAX and that fixed it for me. So maybe you also had one or more set to MAX instead of something else.