# How to resolve the following error in R using ODBC when connecting to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, shiny, odbc

> Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n):
>
> nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2966: 07009: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index

I have cloned the code for an R dashboard from my company's datahub. When I run it, it has this error when it attempts to pull the data from our database. My partner has the exact same code on his machine and it runs just fine. I have read about similar errors and I only can find that it has to do with a bug in the SQL code. I don't think this can be the case because the code works as is on other machines.

Comment: Please see [this](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/86) and [this](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/112).

Answer (score 1):

maybe this similar question will help you

[R DBI ODBC error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3110: 07009: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid Descriptor Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001152/r-dbi-odbc-error-nanodbc-nanodbc-cpp3110-07009-microsoftodbc-driver-13-fo)

If the code works on your coworkers computer, have you compared the EXACT R and Package versions as well as the SQL versions?