# Save or Read data from SQL Server in to R using ODBC package

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

If I want to connect R to a database, do I still need to install driver for R user?

I had done successful connection with server but unable to read/write/fetch the tables.

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
         .connection_string = 'driver={SQL Server};server=DW01;database=AF_DW;trusted_connection=true')
```

Now I can see AF_DW in RStudio connections.

[image]

```
dbListFields(con, "Visits")
```

I can see all the variables in the table "Visits"

```
data <- dbReadTable(con, "Visits")
```

Got an Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Visits'. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. 'SELECT * FROM "Visits")

```
data3 <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM Visits")
```

Got same error

```
data4 <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM Visits")
```

Got same error

```
con_in_R <- dbFetch(dbSendQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM Visits"))
```

Error in (function (cond) : error in evaluating the argument 'res' in selecting a method for function 'dbFetch': nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Visits'. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. 'SELECT * FROM Visits'

Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you image, `Visits` is not stored in the default `dbo` schema as all your queries assume but under the `eCW` schema.

Like most RDBMS's, SQL Server follows the three part name convention for objects (tables, stored procedures, functions): `[database].[schema].[object]` where database is not necessary for a database specific connection and schema not necessary for `dbo` default.

Therefore, you need to reference schema and table name in your attempted queries.

```r
s <- Id(schema = "eCW", table = "Visits")

# READ FROM NON-DEFAULT SCHEMA TABLE
data3 <- dbReadTable(con, s) 
data3 <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM [eCW].[Visits]")

# WRITE TO NON-DEFAULT SCHEMA TABLE
dbWriteTable(conn, s, mydataframe)
dbWriteTable(con, SQL("eCW.Visits"), mydataframe)
```

Comment: I think you have read correctly @Parfait.  AF_DW is a database (catalog) and inside the AF_DW: DW, eCW, WG are the schema. Visits is a table Inside the eCW.

Comment: Hmmm...looks like this is a known issue in R: [R DBI ODBC error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001152/r-dbi-odbc-error-nanodbc-nanodbc-cpp3110-07009-microsoftodbc-driver-13-fo). You may have very [large data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-advanced-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15) (e.g., `varbinary(max)`, `text`, `image`) in table. Try selecting columns and not all with `*`: `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM [eCW].[Visits]`. `dbReadTable` reads all columns in order of `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Then, explicitly `SELECT` all needed columns and choose the large data types as very *last* columns to avoid earlier error (which is not due to rows but columns). To help further, post the [schema of your table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13405572/1422451). Need to see if table holds the large data types.

Comment: Please update your post with such long information and delete above comments, even past comments. Again, try explicitly naming the columns you need and like above R error post shows, place the `varbinary` or `text` at the *end* of `SELECT`.