# How to read a large table (>100 columns (variables) and 100,000 observations) from SQL Server into R using ODBC package

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, odbc

I'm getting an error to read large table into R from SQL Server.

Here is my connection code:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
     .connection_string = 'driver={SQL Server};server=DW01;database=SFAF_DW;trusted_connection=true')
```

Here is a schema of my table which has 149 variables:

[image]

```
data1 <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM [eCW].[Visits]")
```

I got an error from this code probably because of large table.

I would like to reduce the large table (number of observations) applying "VisitDateTime" variable.

```
data2 <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT cast(VisitDateTime as DATETIME) as VisitDateTime FROM [eCW].[Visits] WHERE VisitDateTime>='2019-07-01 00:00:00' AND VisitDateTime<='2020-06-30 12:00:00'")
```

This code selected only "VisitDateTime" variable but I would like to get all (149 variables) from the table.

Hoping to get some efficient codes. Greatly appreciate your help on this. Thank you.

Comment: `select * from ...`

Comment: *"I got an error"* could be anything. It's about as specific as saying "I have a rash" and not including anything like location, color, purulence, or any other factor that might help a medical professional in identifying a possible cause and possible treatments. Please make this question more reproducible; refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Which is it, [tag:sql-server] or [tag:mysql]? It can't be both. (I don't think it matters *which* DBMS you are using, frankly, but please be precise and accurate in your question.)

Comment: Thank you @jarlh, could you please provide more detailed code based on my scenario. It will be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. This is SQL Server. You can see my question at the end, which is "This code (data2) selected only "VisitDateTime" variable but I would like to get all (149 variables) from the table."

Comment: The code you provided at the end doesn't suggest any DBMS, it is only pseudo-code, and doesn't help us to fill in the blanks in your question. The error could be due to: your OS, your R, your network, the DBMS, the table name, the database/schema (`[eCW]`). Some of which might be controlled in R. Some of which might be bad luck timing, fixable by going to get a coffee and trying again. Your error could be *anything*. I don't think it has to do with 150 columns. It might have something to do with "large fields", a bug/feature Microsoft has imposed on ODBC connections (that no other DBMS does).

Comment: Much of that ambiguity may be reduced if you give us the literal text of the error associated with your `"SELECT * FROM ..."` query.

Comment: @r2evans, see OP's [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65014679/1422451) where this stems from. OP is running into this known DBI error: [R DBI ODBC error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001152/r-dbi-odbc-error-nanodbc-nanodbc-cpp3110-07009-microsoftodbc-driver-13-fo). I advised OP to explicitly name columns in `SELECT` and not `*` and place larger text types to the *end* of `SELECT` as above SO post suggests.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait for the clarification and your help.

Comment: That's the error I was suggesting with "large fields", thanks for the clarity @Parfait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your schema, you have many variable length types, `varchar`, of 255 character lengths. As multiple answers on the [similar error post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001152/r-dbi-odbc-error-nanodbc-nanodbc-cpp3110-07009-microsoftodbc-driver-13-fo) suggests, you cannot rely on arbitrary order with `SELECT *` but must explicitly reference each column and place variable lengths toward the *end* of `SELECT` clause. In fact, generally in application code running SQL, avoid `SELECT * FROM`. See [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/1422451)

Fortunately, from your schema output using [**`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you can dynamically develop such a larger named list for `SELECT`. First, adjust and run your schema query as an R data frame with a calculated column to order smallest to largest types and their precision/lengths.

```r
schema_sql <- "SELECT sub.TABLE_NAME, sub.COLUMN_NAME, sub.DATA_TYPE, sub.SELECT_TYPE_ORDER
                    , sub.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, sub.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
                    , sub.NUMERIC_PRECISION, sub.NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, sub.NUMERIC_SCALE
               FROM 
                  (SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
                        , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
                        , NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, NUMERIC_SCALE
                        , CASE DATA_TYPE
                                WHEN 'tinyint'   THEN 1
                                WHEN 'smallint'  THEN 2
                                WHEN 'int'       THEN 3
                                WHEN 'bigint'    THEN 4
                                WHEN 'date'      THEN 5
                                WHEN 'datetime'  THEN 6
                                WHEN 'datetime2' THEN 7
                                WHEN 'decimal'   THEN 8
                                WHEN 'varchar'   THEN 9
                                WHEN 'nvarchar'  THEN 10
                          END AS SELECT_TYPE_ORDER
                   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                   WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'eCW'
                     AND TABLE_NAME = 'Visits'
                  ) sub
               ORDER BY sub.SELECT_TYPE_ORDER
                      , sub.NUMERIC_PRECISION
                      , sub.NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX
                      , sub.NUMERIC_SCALE
                      , sub.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
                      , sub.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH"

visits_schema_df <- dbGetQuery(con, schema_sql)

# BUILD COLUMN LIST FOR SELECT CLAUSE
select_columns <- paste0("[", paste(visits_schema_df$COLUMN_NAME, collapse="], ["), "]")

# RUN QUERY WITH EXPLICIT COLUMNS
data <- dbGetQuery(con, paste("SELECT", select_columns, "FROM [eCW].[Visits]"))
```

---

Above may need adjustment if same error arises. Be proactive and test on your end by isolating the problem columns, column types, etc. A few suggestions include filtering out `DATA_TYPE`, `COLUMN_NAME` or moving around `ORDER` columns in schema query.

```sql
...
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'eCW'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'Visits'
  AND DATA_TYPE IN ('tinyint', 'smallint', 'int')  -- TEST WITH ONLY INTEGER TYPES
```

```sql
...
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'eCW'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'Visits'
  AND NOT DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar')     -- TEST WITHOUT VARIABLE STRING TYPES
```

```sql
...
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'eCW'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'Visits'
  AND NOT DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal', 'datetime2')    -- TEST WITHOUT HIGH PRECISION TYPES
```

```sql
...
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'eCW'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'Visits'
  AND NOT COLUMN_NAME IN ('LastHIVTestResult')     -- TEST WITHOUT LARGE VARCHARs
```

```sql
...
ORDER BY sub.SELECT_TYPE_ORDER                         -- ADJUST ORDERING
       , sub.NUMERIC_SCALE                             
       , sub.NUMERIC_PRECISION
       , sub.NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX
       , sub.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
       , sub.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
```

---

Still another solution is to stitch the R data frame together by their types (adjusting schema query) using the [chain merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/merging-a-lot-of-data-frames) on the primary key (assumed to be `DW_Id`):

```r
final_data <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="DW_Id"),
                     list(data_int_columns,        # SEPARATE QUERY RESULT WITH DW_Id AND INTs IN SELECT
                          data_num_columns,        # SEPARATE QUERY RESULT WITH DW_Id AND DECIMALs IN SELECT 
                          data_dt_columns,         # SEPARATE QUERY RESULT WITH DW_Id AND DATE/TIMEs IN SELECT
                          data_char_columns)       # SEPARATE QUERY RESULT WITH DW_Id AND VARCHARs IN SELECT
              )
```

Comment: I used second option `AND NOT DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar')` and it works. There is a problem with `varchar` data type. I did `AND DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar')` and it did not work, got same error.

Comment: Good. We now isolated which types are the issue. Now create a schema dataset of just `varchar`. Have R dump out the column names and then one by one add them to final `SELECT` (at the end) and see which ones raises the error. I am seeing you have one column, `LastHIVTestResult` at 1,024 character length. Try running all but this one to test. If no error, find the maximum length of this field with data: `SELECT MAX(LEN(LastHIVTestResult)) AS Max_Length FROM [ecW].[Visits];` Then pass number in final query `LEFT(LastHIVTestResult, ###)` or cast/covert to `VARCHAR(###)` on this field.

Comment: Not sure what `102variables` is but as you run it, this would be an SQL error. In R you need to call `paste` or `sprintf` to combine string variables together. Possibly in generating this object, you removed spaces in names. See edit to test if that large varchar alone causes error which involves adding a `WHERE` condition to schema dataset: `AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('LastHIVTestResult', ...)`.

Comment: Sorry `102variables` means all 102 different variables.

Comment: I write column names inside the [...] and then one by one add them to final `SELECT` (at the end) like  `dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT [ID], [Heard aobut]  FROM [eCW].[Visits]")` and it worked but half of `varchar` variables  conflicting with `VisitDateTime` variable.

Comment: Try `CAST` or `CONVERT` for`datetime2` to simpler `datetime`. For `varchar`, find max length of existing data in `varchar` and `CAST` to smaller `varchar`s in `SELECT`. I don't know your data but ask yourself do values run to 255 characters? If still a challenge, see very last solution to merge together an R data frame from separate query results. You really have to play around with solution. Please try your best. There's no single one-liner for your issue. Finally, have SQL Server dump data to text to read into R. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Parfait