multiple datatypes from sql in r studio
I'm trying to load a table from sql database in R studio. Table has columns with datatypes navachar, date, int. table doesn't load if i try:
query_subset <- "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.bikerides"
bikerides_data_subset <- dbGetQuery(con, query_subset)
print(bikerides_data_subset)

but if i specify columns of same datatype in same query it will load. if i try to load columns with different data types even with specifying it won't load & give error like :
query_subset <- "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.bikerides"
bikerides_data_subset <- dbGetQuery(con, query_subset)


Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3182: 07009
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index
Warning message:
In dbClearResult(rs) : Result already cleared

this works because it has same data types but as soon as i add int or date column it gives error
query <- "SELECT TOP 10 ride_id, rideable_type, member_casual,start_station_name, end_station_name FROM dbo.bikerides"
bikerides_data <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
print(bikerides_data)


What's with the mysql tag? It's probably related to ODBC driver & MS SQL Server - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001152/r-dbi-odbc-error-nanodbc-nanodbc-cpp3110-07009-microsoftodbc-driver-13-fo  . What happens when you move nvarchar columns to last positions of your select statment?

Please show your dbConnect line, redacting confidential info as necessary but not driver. Per this Git issue, using latest MSSQL ODBC driver and ODBC package should resolve this often discussed error. Be sure to research before asking!
